# Change frontpage pagination to use a more/previous style

Tags: 7, paging

The standard pagination on my site looks like this:

[image]

I'd like to alter the config (or install a module, etc) that will help me use this simpler type of pagination:

[image]

How can I reconfigure my site to use this kind of pagination? Do you know of a module that will let me choose this style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use [theme_pager()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!pager.inc/function/theme_pager/7)

Place this function in your template.php file and clear theme registry:

```
/**
 * Implementation of HOOK_pager().
 * $variables: An associative array containing:
 *  tags: An array of labels for the controls in the pager.
 *  element: An optional integer to distinguish between multiple pagers on one page.
 *  parameters: An associative array of query string parameters to append to the pager links.
 *  quantity: The number of pages in the list.
 */
function YOURTHEME_pager($variables) {
  $tags = $variables['tags'];
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $parameters = $variables['parameters'];
  $quantity = $variables['quantity'];
  global $pager_page_array, $pager_total;

  $li_previous = theme('pager_previous', array('text' => (isset($tags[1]) ? $tags[1] : t('‹ Previous Posts')), 'element' => $element, 'interval' => 1, 'parameters' => $parameters));
  $li_next = theme('pager_next', array('text' => (isset($tags[3]) ? $tags[3] : t('More Posts ›')), 'element' => $element, 'interval' => 1, 'parameters' => $parameters));

  if ($pager_total[$element] > 1) {

    // PREVIOUS
    if ($li_previous) {
      $items[] = array(
        'class' => array('pager-previous'), 
        'data' => $li_previous,
      );
    }

    // NEXT
    if ($li_next) {
      $items[] = array(
        'class' => array('pager-next'), 
        'data' => $li_next,
      );
    }

    // OUTPUT
    return '<h2 class="element-invisible">' . t('Pages') . '</h2>' . theme('item_list', array(
      'items' => $items, 
      'attributes' => array('class' => array('pager')),
    ));
  }
}
```